# Apache Nifi 1.7.1 Flatten Json with delimiter

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am using the Flatten Json processor with delimiter `_` , this works fine in so far that it does flatten nested records. But I also noticed that it interferes with keys which already have "_" in them. For eg:

```
{
"first_name": "myfirstname",
"last_name":  "mylastname",
"address": {
            "billing": "mybilling",
            "shipping": "myshipping"
           }
}
```

flattened to:

```
{
"[\"first_name\"]": "myfirstname",
"[\"last_name\"]":  "mylastname",
"address_billing": "mybilling",
"address_shipping": "myshipping"
 }
```

while, '`address`' record is flattened as expected, the keys `first_name` and `last_name` which have an `_` character are also disturbed. Is there a way I can circumvent this? (perhaps a way to escape non record types?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To workaround this issue you can use either

- **JoltTransformJson** processor

  **(or)**
- Keep the **seperator(like '|','-'..etc)** in **FlattenJson** which is
  `not present in key` names.

> **1. Using JoltTransformJson Processor:**

**Spec:**

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "address": {
        "*": "address_&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "first_name" : "myfirstname",
  "last_name" : "mylastname",
  "address_billing" : "mybilling",
  "address_shipping" : "myshipping"
}
```

> **2.FlattenJson Processor:**

[image]

**Output:**

```
{
    "first_name": "myfirstname",
    "last_name": "mylastname",
    "address|billing": "mybilling",
    "address|shipping": "myshipping"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NiFi 1.7.1 uses an external library called [json-flattener](https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener) in version 0.5.0.
This currently [unconditionally](https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener/blob/json-flattener-0.5.0/src/main/java/com/github/wnameless/json/flattener/JsonFlattener.java#L378) checks for reserved characters and replaces them with the form you're seeing.
The reason for this is so that a document can be unambiguously unflattened again.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener/pull/25) that implements an option to disable this feature but it hasn't been merged since July 2017.

In short: There is nothing you can do within NiFi itself to circumvent this at the moment.